# sveltekit Hash-based routing

Tags: routes, svelte, preload, prefetch, sveltekit

I'm pretty new to svelte and especially SvelteKit. Currently, I'm working on 2 projects.

The 1st one is a SPA in which I use [svelte-spa-router](https://github.com/ItalyPaleAle/svelte-spa-router) to manage the different states and bring the ability to navigate back and forward like we would do in an old-school website.
This works perfectly :)

The 2nd project is a SvelteKit app. I have 3 use cases:

1. Search a product
2. Create a product
3. Display the top 10 products

In the first place, I thought that it would be interesting to be able to prefetch some kind of JSON data if needed for each use case, but on the other hand, I didn't want to create a route page for each sub use case because I didn't want the page to refresh each time the user makes a simple action. So, I'm using 3 routes to navigate between these 3 "use cases":

```bash
src/routes/search_product/+page.svelte
src/routes/create_product_page/+page.svelte
src/routes/show_top_10_products/+page.svelte
```

Now, I have a problem ... there's 3 steps to create a product page. These 3 steps are represented by the 3 different Svelte components below:

1. `EnterProductBasicInfo.svelte`
2. `UploadPictures.svelte`
3. `GivePrices.svelte`

If the user is in the process of creating a product page and is at step 2), he is shown the `UploadPictures.svelte` component .... but if he press the back button, he will quit the `create_product_page` route instead of getting back to step 1) that is the `EnterProductBasicInfo.svelte` component.

So, I was thinking that I may use the `svelte-spa-router` that I've used for the SPA, but I'm asking experts here if there is another built-in solution in SvelteKit to be able to manage routes without refreshing the whole page each time a route changes. If you have some good link about SPA, SSR, preloading vs prefetching, I'll take it cause it's still a bit blurry to me.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think adding svelte-spa-router would be overkill.

In SvelteKit pages are rendered on the server (SSR) initially, but once loaded, pages are not refreshed each time a route change. It will behave like a SPA but with autmatic route based code-splitting and data loading and built-in.
Prefetching is the act of preloading the code-splitted javascript & data for instant navigation.

**Option 1**
Create a "src/routes/create_product" folder with the 3 steps as subroutes "src/routes/create_product/step1/+page.svelte", etc and a +layout.svelte inside the create_product folder to share state and UI.

**Option 2**
But it that doesn't fit your use-case, you can also implement a simple hash based section using the [page store](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-stores):

```html
<script>
  import { page } from "$app/stores";
</script>

{#if $page.url.hash === "#step2"}
  <a href="#step1">Back to step 1</a>
{:else}
  <a href="#step2">Goto step 2</a>
{/if}
```

Comment: Just for the record, the key thing using SSR is that pages don't reload as long as routes shares the same `__layout.svelte`.